# How can I track controller movement events with WebVR and A-Frame?

Tags: javascript, aframe, virtual-reality, webvr, oculus

I have a WebVR page made with A-Frame, using an Oculus Rift with touch controllers. I have these elements for the controllers:

```
<a-entity oculus-touch-controls="hand: right" right-control-listener></a-entity>
<a-entity oculus-touch-controls="hand: left" left-control-listener></a-entity>
<a-entity laser-controls="hand: right" raycaster="objects: .clickable"></a-entity>
```

I want to select or grip an object and move it as a controller moves. But I haven't been able to find an event for controller movement. *Mousemove* doesn't seem to be available, even though *mouseup* and *mousedown* are.

Comment: FYI, `laser-controls` already supports Oculus Touch. The `oculus-touch-controls` components are redundant. They are set by `laser-controls`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `tick` method. If you want to track an entity position or rotation do:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('track', {
  init: function () {
     this.trackedEl = document.querySelector('#trackedEntity');
  },

  tick: function () {
     this.el.object3D.position.x = this.trackedEl.object3D.position.x;
  }
});
```

See a [demo](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/rowan-woolen?path=track-component.js:7:4) where the red ball tracks the x position of the camera (moved with wasd keys). You can do something similar using an appropriate selector for the controller entity you want to track. e.g: `document.querySelector('[laser-controls]');`